# Completion block gets called at loadView every time the app becomes active

Tags: objective-c, block

I have a weird bug, here is my code on my rootViewController

```
- (void)loadView
{
    [super loadView];
    PPMultiplayerManager *mpManager = [PPGameHandler sharedGameHandler].multiplayerManager;
    [mpManager loadManagerAtViewController:self withCompletion:^{
        [self animateSplash];
    }];
}
```

My question is, why does `animateSplash` get called every time `appDidBecomeActive:` is called (multitask-in/out)? I only call `[self animateSplash]` inside this completionBlock.

Comment: Unrelated: Is this iOS or OS X? At least with iOS, you must NOT call `[super loadView]` when you override the `UIViewController loadView` method. Don't know about OS X.

Comment: i probably saw the issue, maybe these line of codes are the cause:
GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
localPlayer.authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error) { ... }

Comment: this is iOS, so why don't we call [super loadView] for iOS? @maddy

Comment: Read the docs for `loadView`.

Comment: See the note in [Creating a View Programmatically](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH10-SW36) section of the _Resource Management in View Controllers_ chapter of the _View Controller Programming Guide._ I can't tell, though, whether he's really creating view programmatically, or whether he's doing stuff that really belongs in `viewDidLoad`.